# Get the index of a specific string from a dynamically generated output

Tags: linux, shell, sed, awk, sh

I tried a lot of things, but now I am at my wit's end.
My problem is I need the index of a specific string from my dynamically generated output.

In example, I want the index from the string 'cookie' in this output:

```
1337 cat dog table cookie 42
```

So in this example I would need this result:

```
5
```

One problem is that I need that number for a later executed awk command. Another problem is that this generated output has a flexible length and you are not able to 'sed' something with . - or something else. There is no such pattern like this.

Cheers

Comment: U want index of word "cookie" right?

Comment: Right! The problem is that the provided solution below, does not work for the pattern of my output. I think the problem is the tr command and the replacement of ' ', sometimes there are no spaces between, I searched for my string 'pdu' in my output. I received one correct one and the other was just a wait with three lines then another wait and thats it. But simply yes, I need the index.

Comment: @Marcel give another example of `sometimes there are no spaces between, I searched for my string 'pdu' in my output.` with expected output.

Comment: Your example shows your concept of an "index" as being the relative position of space-separated strings. Given that, I can't imagine what you mean by "sometimes there are no spaces between" so as @Kent says, please show some more representative input and expected output that covers other cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just create an array mapping the string value to it's index and then print the entry:

```
$ cat file
1337 cat dog table cookie 42

$ awk -v v="cookie" '{v2i[v]=0; for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) v2i[$i]=i; print v2i[v]}' file            
5
```

The above will print 0 if the string doesn't exist as a field on the given line.

By the way, you say you need that number output from the above "for a later executed awk command". Wild idea - why not do both steps in one awk command?

Answer (score 1):

Ugly, but possible:

```
echo '1337 cat dog table cookie 42' \
    | tr ' ' '\n'                   \
    | grep -Fn cookie               \
    | cut -f1 -d:
```

Comment: Right! The problem is this the provided solution does not work for the pattern of my output, because it is a log which is more complex. I think the problem is the tr command and the replacement of ' ', sometimes there are no spaces between, I searched for my string 'pdu' in my output. I received one correct one and the other was just a wait with three lines then another wait and thats it. But simply yes, I need the index.

Comment: @Marcel: Show a line where this does not work so the solution can be fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to find position of word in a string using `gnu awk` (due to RS), and store it to a variable.

```
pat="cookie"
pos=$(echo "1337 cat dog table cookie 42" | awk '{print NF+1;exit}' RS="$pat")
echo "$pos"
5
```

If you do not have `gnu awk`

```
pat="cookie"
pos=$(echo "1337 cat dog table cookie 42" | awk '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) if ($i~p) print i}' p="$pat")
echo "$pos"
5
```

Comment: To clarify - those solutions are searching for an RE, not a string, and not a complete word so if you wanted to find the index of a full string like "a.g" they'd match on the middle of "barge" or anything else that contained the letters a and g separated by 1 character.

Answer (score 1):

Here is pure bash way of doing it with arrays, no sed or awk or GNUs required ;-)

```
# Load up array, you would use your own command in place of echo
array=($(echo 1337 cat dog table cookie 42))
# Show what we have
echo ${array[*]}
1337 cat dog table cookie 42
# Find which element contains our pattern
for ((i=0;i<${#array[@]};i++)); do [ ${array[$i]} == "cookie" ] && echo $(($i+1)); done
5
```

Of course, you could set a variable to use later instead of echoing $i+1. You may also want some error checking in case pattern isn't found, but you get the idea!

Comment: Providing a text manipulation solution with `no sed or awk ... required` is like providing a way to put screws into wood with `no screwdriver required`. You can do it but....

Comment: :-) It works, so it's an answer and a possibility for the OP to consider. And it's prettier than at least one other solution suggested!

Comment: Yeah, I get it, it's just the OP might think there's some intrinsic value in trying not to use sed or awk when the reality is that jobs like this is exactly what they were created for and are best at.

Comment: There could be some value in doing it in bash without having to create thousands of extra processes if this sits in the middle of a fat loop...

Comment: No. The value would be in removing the fat loop and re-writing it in awk or some other tool. Loops in shell are usually the wrong solution.

Comment: I maintain that avoiding creating unnecessary processes is generally a "good thing" - you know how "cat file | awk ..." annoys everyone - that my solution works and is no less readable or maintainable than most other solutions shown here... that said, I would probably use Jotne's myself :-)

Comment: +1, but on systems that do not use `bash` as the default shell, this is just as much an external requirement as `awk` or `sed`.

Comment: The bash command isn't as maintainable as the sed or awk commands, though. For example, sed and awk solutions handle multi-line input as-is while you'd need to manually write another loop around the bash code above to process multi-line input. UUOC annoys people because it's text that's useless at best (and has negative impacts in some cases eg stopping awk from populating FILENAME), not because it spawns processes. Using awk for this is useful despite the extra process (which is rarely noticeable, never mind an actual issue), as it's more concise, robust, and extensible than a bash script.

Comment: I disagree. Both solutions store items in an array and pick one that matches, so my solution is no harder to maintain than any other - in fact, mine doesn't require the maintenance programmer to know "awk" or "sed", so it could be argued that it is easier. The OP has not stated any requirement to handle multi-line input, so that is a non-issue. And, my objection to UUOCs _is_ largely based on creating pointless load on servers - but that may be because I spend a lot of time consulting on solving performance issues.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another answer, not using arrays, or "sed" or "awk" or "tr", just based on the bash IFS separating the values for you:

```
#!/bin/bash
output="cat dog mouse cookie 42"  # Or output=$(yourProgram)
f=0 # f will be your answer
i=0 # i counts the fields
for x in $output; do \
   ((i++)); [[ "$x" = "cookie" ]] && f=$i; \
done
echo $f
```

Result:

```
 4
```

Or you can put it all on one line, if you remove the backslashes, like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
output="cat dog mouse cookie 42"  # Or output=$(yourProgram)
f=0;i=0;for x in $output; do ((i++)); [[ "$x" = "cookie" ]] && f=$i; done
echo $f
```

Explanation:

The "[[a=b]] && c" part is just shorthand for

```
if [a=b]; then
   c
fi
```

It relies on shortcut evaluation of logicals. Basically, we are asking shell to determine if the two statements "a equals  b" AND the statement "c" are both true. If a is not equal to b, it already knows it doesn't need to evaluate c because they already can't both be true - so f doesn't get the value of i. If, on the other hand, a is equal to b, the shell must still evaluate statement "c" to see if it is also true - and when it does so, f will get the value of i.

Answer (score 0):

```
Pat="cookie"
YourInput | sed -n "/${Pat}/ {s/.*/ & /;s/ ${Pat} .*/I/;s/[[:blank:]\{1,\}[^[:blank:]\{1,\}/I/g
   s/I\{9\}/9/;s/I\{8\}/8/;s/I\{7\}/7/;s/IIIIII/6/;s/IIIII/5/;s/IIII/4/;s/III/3/;s/II/2/;s/I/1/
   p;q;}
 $ s/.*/0/p"
```

if there is more than 9 cols, a more complex sed could be made or pass through a `wc -c` instead

Comment: That is not looking for a string, it's looking for an RE. `a more complex sed could be made` - a terrifying threat :-).

Comment: counting on sed is possibls e but a bit heavy in this case because there a certainly less than 9 columns to count. So yes a more complex, already done here is possible four counting until 1 million which is certainly not occuring based on this sample. What do you mean by searching a RE and not a string ? Sed is always looking for RE and not string

Comment: Exactly. The OP said "I need the index of a specific **string**" not "I need the index of a specific RE" so sed is not a good choice as it cannot search for strings.

Comment: right, word is as you write but not the sample. I think OP say string for word  because there is no string in the sample string (except itself) and it extract the 5th word of the string (no other separator than space in the sample) so or the are string of 1 word with separator or , and it suite better, OP mean word for string (which is literal string of char, blank separated)

Comment: I also took the OP as wanting to search for a literal string of chars, blank separated, and as such I assume he wants `.`, for example, treated literally just like every other char in his string rather than as an RE wildcard. Sure, you can start escaping characters and jumping through hoops but you cannot automate that to accommodate any user input and the far simpler solution is just to search for a string instead of an RE.

Comment: sed and search of "pure" string is not easy. Escaping of serached string to translate it in pattern sed wil use to correspond to string is not easy, right. awk maybe but certainly a fgrep could act like this

Comment: Again, that's my point, this is not an appropriate job for sed. Also, yes fgrep searches for strings but how would you use fgrep to return the "index" of where that string exists in the line? I'm just saying - this particular problem is a job for awk.